# Get route from unordered set of tuples

Tags: python, routes, tuples

We want to solve the following problem in Python:
There is a route with arcs/tuples `[i,j]`. For example: `[(0,10),(11,0),(10,11)]`.

- Not all lists have the same length (each list can have x amount of tuples).
- These arcs need to become the following route `[0,10,11,0]`.

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: i didn't understand the question

Comment: @Jayjayyy Yes we always start and end at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is just an example to learn how to do certain things with Python? Have a look at the code below for a very basic approach how you would be able to do it. It's not optimized code, though.

```
# Define a route by the steps you have to take from one origin to the
# new destination. These steps are provided as a list of tuples where
# the first element is the origin and the second element is the destination.
steps = [(0,10), (11,0), (10,11)]

# Start with origin 0
route = [0]

# Repeat until no steps left to take
while len(steps) > 0:
    # The former destination is the last element of the current route
    former_destination = route[-1]
    # Browse through all remaining steps
    for i, (origin, destination) in enumerate(steps):
        # Skip this step if its origin and the former destination don't match
        if origin != former_destination:
            continue
        # Remove the current step
        steps.pop(i)
        # Add new destination
        route.append(destination)
        break

print(route)
```

Which will print

```
[0, 10, 11, 0]
```

Comment: No question, it was very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and remove nodes as you look them up:

```py
nodes = [(0, 10), (11, 0), (10, 11)]
d = dict(nodes)
chain = [0]
while d:
    chain.append(d.pop(chain[-1]))
```